# How to get 3 skulls (or less) system to improve faction reputation after finishing main campaign in BattleTech flashpoint?

Tags: battletech

I am playing flashpoint and recently got to open the black market which I consider to be an awesome way to get hands on +++ items.

Price and items in the black market depend on reputation with local pirate organization. I have hated rating with local pirate organization and I would like to improve it. Problem is I have finished main campaign and lowest star system load rating is 3.5+(skulls)

[image]

At hated, I can only accept 3(skull) missions from the local pirate faction.
[image]

Does it mean that there is no way for me to improve rating with local pirate organization and to subsequently get better items at cheaper prices from black market?

**Is there a way to get 3 skulls (or less system) after finishing main campaign in BattleTech flashpoint? Or some other way to improve faction reputation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out myself. It would appear I haven't been looking hard enough!

There are Detroit and Un Cruinine systems that have 3 skulls, they are in the section of the map that belongs to local governments,  in the center of Rimworld.

[image]

So now I only need to fly in often enough to check if there are contracts by pirates and I should get the reputation...

Also, I while having hated reputation I was able to accept 3.5 skull mission.

[image]

Comment: My notes suggest that Bellerophon (locals) should also be a three skull system